When should the "terms" argument be specified in sjPlot::plot_model function?
Basically, the title.
I am refering to the predictors vs response plots, not the model coefficients plot. For example, this code:
sjPlot::plot_model(model, type = "eff")
Lately, I always need to specify the "terms" argument to avoid Error messages. I read it might be due to NAs and interference with other packages, but I could not make it work without the terms argument.
Also, could using nlme::gls funtion to fit the model be part of the problem?
